# Smarty (& Codeigniter): What is current path?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, codeigniter-2

This is my first time playing with CI & Smarty, and I am a trying to build a relative URI so I can load a JS file.

I took a guess at the appropriate path to use for importing the little js plugin, and can use some guidance.
I dropped the plugin into `www/js`, and since all initial calls go through `www/index.php`,  my first attempt was simply `src='js/blah/blah/blah.js'`.

If there is a way to echo the path from a TPL, I figure that would give me enough info.
Is this info avail in Smarty?
Is there a better way to achieve my intended goals (loading a JS file) ?

Comment: See [`base_url`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

When loading resources in an html file (js, css, images, etc.), you are better off using absolute paths. It is the browser that is requesting these resources and not CI or Smarty, so I would just use:

```
/js/blah/blah/blah.js
```

Where your root is the web-server root (`www/` in your example).

Comment: Hmmm, thanks .. That is EXACTLY what I expected .. I wonder why it's not working .. Maybe I'll re-comb for type-o's or something.  ???

Comment: For some reason, I just couldn't get that going .. so I simply plopped the plugin onto our live public-facing server, and used that URI instead. (which is working fine, BTW)

Comment: @mOrloff Very strange, is perhaps CI rewriting the paths?